# Can there be net condensation into a pool of water?

Tags: water, equilibrium, evaporation, condensation

I'm curious about the equilibrium of evaporation and condensation. Given that the surface area of a dehumidifier's evaporation coil at 4C is proportional to the rate of condensation, how would the rate of evaporation and condensation of 4C water relate to its surface area?

Is there a condition, such as a warm humid room, where a pool of 4C water would increase in volume? Or, would evaporation always be dominant?

I can understand how rain droplets form but, they have a tiny surface area. As the surface area of a pool of water increases, could net condensation occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course. On a hot, humid day, if you have a glass of ice water you'll get water droplets condensing onto the glass. The same happens onto the surface of the water, you just can't tell the difference between newly condensed water and the pre-existing water.